# Rendering pyramid in openGL

Tags: opengl, rendering

I am trying to render a pyramid in openGL as basic practice, but the position of the vertices is not rendering as expected. I want the pyramid centered on the world coordinate system and the points I am using are as such.

```
glm::vec3 pos0(-width/2, -height/2, width/2); //front left vertex
glm::vec3 pos1(width/2, -height/2, width/2); //front right vertex
glm::vec3 pos2(-width/2, -height/2, -width/2);//back left vertex
glm::vec3 pos3(width/2, -height/2, -width/2); //back right vertex
glm::vec3 pos4(0.0f, height/2, 0.0f); //top vertex
```

I am drawing the pyramid with GL_DRAW_TRIANGLES in this order and showing CCW as the front face.

```
indices.push_back(5); /////////// front face
indices.push_back(2);
indices.push_back(1);
indices.push_back(5); /////////// left face
indices.push_back(3);
indices.push_back(1); 
indices.push_back(5); /////////// back face
indices.push_back(3);
indices.push_back(4);
indices.push_back(5); /////////// right face
indices.push_back(4);
indices.push_back(2); 
indices.push_back(1); /////////// left bottom
indices.push_back(3);
indices.push_back(2); 
indices.push_back(2); /////////// right bottom
indices.push_back(3);
indices.push_back(4);
```

I expect the first three points to be the front face of the triangle, but for some reason that doesn't seem to be the case. The colors are not what would be expected (each vertex has its own color) and the height doesn't even seem tor each the top of the pyramid. Does anyone see a problem with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL indices are 0-based. With 5 vertices, the range of indices must be from 0 to 4.